# Unable to pass form data to Servlet

Tags: java, forms, servlets, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I have written a sample code to pass form data from a `html` page to a `servlet`. Here are my source codes,

**StudentForm.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML Form</title>
</head>Title
<body>
    <form action="FormDataServlet" method="get">
    FName:<input type="text" name="fName"> <br/>
    LName:<input type="text" name="lName"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**FormDataServlet**

```
package com.kasun.student.form;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 * Created by kausn on 5/24/17.
 */
@WebServlet(name = "/FormDataServlet")
public class FormDataServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter=response.getWriter();
        printWriter.print("<html><head></head><body>");
        printWriter.print("The F name of the student is "+request.getParameter("fName"));
        printWriter.print("The L name of the student is "+request.getParameter("lName"));
        printWriter.print("</body></html>");

    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletDemo1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.kasun.servlet.demo.ServletDemo1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FormDataServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.kasun.student.form.FormDataServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletDemo1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletDemo1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FormDataServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FormDataServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

But when I submit the form it says `404 error` that is because it is calling the servlet that exists in `http://localhost:63342/ServletDemo/web/FormDataServlet?fName=sfddfddfd&lName=dfdf` this path. I know for sure that this is where the bug is, but how to fix this? (Please find the screenshot of package structure as below)

[image]

Comment: The .html file belongs at the root, not under WEB-INF.  What is the name of the WAR you package this into?  404 means you don't have the URL right.  I think it should be http://localhost:63342/war/FormDataServlet?....

Comment: The `action` attribute of the `<form>` element controls the URL to which the form data will be submitted.  You might consider using a URL that it relative to the document root (`/some/path/FormDataServlet`) instead of one relative to the containing document as you do now.

Comment: Note also that the name given in your `@WebServlet` annotation is relative to the web application's context root, which could very easily be different from the host HTTP server's document root.